# How to fetch/embed youtube video based on your own url?

Tags: youtube

I saw this site http://www.rainymood.com where you can add the youtube link in the url , by example rainymood.com/watch?v=0gcu3GI3nA4 and it will embed the video on the site .My question is how can you do that .I mean , for example I have www.mysite.com and I want to embed a youtube video based on my url like so : www.mysite.com/watch?v=0gcu3GI3nA4 and then show it on the site .I hope you can understand me :)
Edit : What I use is this : http://www.w3lessons.info/2012/01/04/fetch-embed-videos-from-url-using-php-and-jquery/ .What i need now is instead entering the url in the form ,the video to be embed using my url with the /watch?v=id ending .

Comment: Could you please provide an example of what you have tried?

Comment: This what I got so far : http://deian.smart-start.ro/test/2/ .I can embed a video from a given url but I dont know how to do it from my own url .

Comment: It would be better if you updated your question, with the parts of code that are relevant rather than linking your test site. That way when you take down the test site when things are working, the question remains helpful for other people doing the same thing.